# why spamc keeps getting me 0/0 when I test it?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, spam, spamassassin

on my centos 5 I've installed spamassassin and I want to execute it from php using the command line client.

The problem is that each time I run it, I get as result:

> 0/0

here is how I run it

```
echo "VIAGRA" | /usr/bin/spamc -c -F spamassasin.conf
```

this is my config file

```
# SpamAssassin config file for version 3.x
# NOTE: NOT COMPATIBLE WITH VERSIONS 2.5 or 2.6
# See http://www.yrex.com/spam/spamconfig25.php for earlier versions
# Generated by http://www.yrex.com/spam/spamconfig.php (version 1.50)

# How many hits before a message is considered spam.
required_score           7.5

# Encapsulate spam in an attachment (0=no, 1=yes, 2=safe)
report_safe             1

# Enable the Bayes system
use_bayes               1

# Enable Bayes auto-learning
bayes_auto_learn              1

# Enable or disable network checks
skip_rbl_checks         0
use_razor2              1
use_dcc                 1
use_pyzor               1

# Mail using languages used in these country codes will not be marked
# as being possibly spam in a foreign language.
# - english 
ok_languages            en 

# Mail using locales used in these country codes will not be marked
# as being possibly spam in a foreign language.
ok_locales              en
```

any idea?

As always, thank you

Answer (score 2):

That's not an RFC822 e-mail, spamassassin may simply be giving up.

You might have some test mails in /usr/share/doc/spamassassin/examples/ that are a better test.

Comment: I know what you say. but that was a quick test before start building the application. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the answer what pretty easy..... the spamassassin was down during testings :P

Answer (score 1):

Rather than testing using the string 'VIAGRA', use sample spam (sample-spam.txt) or the [GTUBE](http://spamassassin.apache.org/gtube/) string:

```
XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X
```

GTUBE is the anti-spam equivalent of EICAR.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware he already figured it out, I just thought this bit would be helpful :p